# How can i hide and show stack navigator header in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I hide and then show header(stack navigator) by pressing a button ?

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        header : null
    }
}
```

This code set header to `null` and hide header but i can't show it again.

Comment: your code seems to work https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for every one. `headerVisible` property doesn't work.

There is another property called `headerMode`, it just works in stack navigator's config and **we can't change it** in our screen :

```
const StackNaviagtor = createStackNavigator({
        showScreen: {
            screen: MyScreen
        }
    }, {
            headerMode: 'none'
        })
```

only `header` property in navigationOption work and we can change it in our screen

**the solution is :**

```
import { Header } from "react-navigation";   
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
             header: navigation.getParam('isFullscreen') ? null : (headerProps) => <Header {...headerProps} />
    }
```

and then:

```
render() {
    let isFullscreen = this.props.navigation.getParam('isFullscreen');
    return (
         <Button title='Full Screen' onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.setParams({ isFullscreen: !isFullscreen }) }} />
    )
```

Comment: also we can use this : ` header: navigation.getParam('isFullscreen') ? null : this.header `

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
static navigationOptions = {
     headerVisible: this.state.headerVisible,
};
```

And In the constructor Initialise the state by

```
this.state = {headerVisible: true}
```

And on the buttonPress You can change the state by

```
<Button onPress={() => this.setState({headerVisible: !this.state.headerVisible})} />
```

Comment: the header property in navigationOptions doesn't work with boolean value

Comment: also we dont acces state in navigationOptions because of static

Comment: there is a property for navigation options named headerVisible

Answer (score 0):

Do you could try this?

```js
this.state={
     header: null
}
static navigationOptions = {
     header: this.state.header,
};
...
headerfunc(){
 if(this.state.header === null){
   this.setSate({
         header: ""
    });
  }else{
   this.setSate({
         header: null
    });
 }
}
...
<Button onPress={() => this.headerfunc()} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom function to handle the header visibility.

Create a handler function in your screen component,

```
toggleHeader=()=>{
   let currentVal = this.props.navigation.getParam('isHeaderVisible', true);
   this.props.navigation.setParams({ isHeaderVisible: !currentVal });
}
```

Add this handler function to your `Button`

```
render(){
       ...
       <Button onPress={() => this.toggleHeader()} />
       ...
    }
```

Finally, add `static navigationOptions` in your screen,

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => { 
   let headerVisible = navigation.getParam('isHeaderVisible',true);
   return {
     headerVisible
   }
}
```